# Magento Magestore One step checkout GOOGLE API autocomplete auto suggest NOT working

Tags: onestepcheckout

tried everything...im pretty well versed...anyone who can confirm that this actually works?

Yes I have the key put in the box with the box marked "YES"

Comment: try contacting developers of extension once